# Derive a parse tree from given expression

Tags: parse-tree

I am having trouble creating a parse tree for the expression:
4 + (5 * 7).  I made one for the expression 4 + 5 * 7 but now the parentheses are throwing me off.  Here is what I have for the first parse tree:

[image]

But like I said the expression 4 + (5 * 7) is throwing me off due to the parentheses.  The grammar rules are:

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The parentheses don't show up in the parse tree, they only determine the shape of the parse tree. You could trying to draw (4 + 5) * 7 as an exercise, to observe how a different order of operations leads to a different parse tree --- so that the information of the parentheses is stored in the shape of the parse tree, rather than as separate nodes or edges.

Comment: Wow that makes total sense.  So instead of taking the parentheses as literals they just determine where those numbers fall in the parse tree?

Comment: Yeah, the numbers and also the operations. Another thing to leave out of the parse tree is the name of the rules btw. So you could just use the `+`, `*`, `4`, `5`and `7` nodes to create the tree. The operations would then each have two children, the numbers none.

Comment: Thank you for all of the pointers.  It is my first class dealing with this type of work.